# Is there any way to subscribe & send messaging center for generic type class using mvvm light Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

That's how i am doing it right now, is there any better solution for making this generic

```
MessagingCenter.Send(this, "XYZ", "XYZ" + " Recieved");

MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MyService, string>(this, "XYZ", async (sender, arg) =>
{
     //TO-DO
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How we use to send message using messaging center in xamarin forms:-
This is the line I have used In bellow method:-

```
  MessagingCenter.Send(this, typeof(T).Name, typeof(T).Name + " Recieved");
```

DatabaseService.cs   --- I am sending this message from "DatabaseService.cs" so writting this for reference in first paramenter, in second parameter  typeof(T).Name where "T" is generic class.(T is Azure Table name after downloading done I am sending message to identify the data is arrived from Azure server and saved in Local DB) , second paramenter in the bellow method is also typeof(T).Name which referes to key for which sender and receiver are subscribed and "Receieved" is arguments that I am passing to Identify that the data is received or deleted from store to identify which sort of operation I have performed on SQLite DB.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Function to retrive Records from Azure Server and insert/Update those into localDB .
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Table Name</typeparam>
    /// <param name="data">Records retrived from Azure Server that are being insrted to localDB.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>


        public async Task InsertDataToLocalDB<T>(List<T> data)
        {
            List<JObject> jDatas = new List<JObject>();
            for (int index = 0; index < data.Count; index++)
            {
                jDatas.Add(JObject.FromObject(data[index]));
            }
            try
            {
                await _store.UpsertAsync(typeof(T).Name, jDatas, true);  //_Store is MobileServiceSQLiteStore SQLite store
            }
            catch (Exception ww)
            {

                //throw;
            }


            MessagingCenter.Send(this, typeof(T).Name, typeof(T).Name + " Recieved");
        }
```

How we use to subcribe to messages:-

```
   MessagingCenter.Subscribe<DatabaseService, string>(this, "Notification", async (sender, arg) =>
            {
               //After Receiving Notifications from server Call Refresh Command
                await RefreshCommand.ExecuteAsync();
            });
```